# How to prove that \$I_3=Vi/R1\$ in a darlingtonpair circuit with opamp when \$\beta_2\to\infty\$?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, bjt, math, darlington

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq0O3o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I prove that \$I_3=Vi/R1\$ when \$\beta_2\to\infty\$?

Comment: Hopefully you can see that the current through R3 is basically that through R1.  Mentally erase the transistors so that the op-amp is driving R1 directly, and ask yourself what an op-amp is supposed to do.  Then recognize that the transistors are there just to give the op-amp greater power drive capability than it has on its own.

Comment: Set the diff. voltage at the opamp input to zero.

Comment: It is true because of a negative feedback loop and an ideal opamp used in the circuit. So the opamp will output such a voltage at his output to force Vin = V_at_inverting_input. Thus infinite beta of a BJT 's is not needed in this case. You only need an ideal opamp.

Comment: I think, only for an infinite beta value we have Ic=Ie (as the question contains the current through R3)

Comment: @LvW You are right, I missed that fact.

Comment: Downvoting because you accepted the give-me-an-answer to this *un-attempted homework* rather than taking time to work through the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unattempted homework

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> First, I will use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve your problem.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftkfTZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{T}=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_2\tag1$$
- $$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{T}+\text{I}_3\tag2$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta_1\$:
  $$\beta_1=\frac{\text{I}_2}{\text{I}_0}\tag3$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta_2\$:
  $$\beta_2=\frac{\text{I}_3}{\text{I}_\text{T}}\tag4$$
- Emitter voltage \$\text{T}_1\$:
  $$\text{V}_{\text{BE}_1}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\tag5$$
- Emitter voltage \$\text{T}_2\$:
  $$\text{V}_{\text{BE}_2}=\text{V}_2-\text{V}_5\tag5$$

Using [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write:

$$\text{I}_\text{b}=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag6$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_5}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag7
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_\text{i}=\text{V}_5\tag8$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{I}_3\$:

$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\beta_2}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\beta_2\right)}\tag9$$

Where I used Mathematica-code to solve for that:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{IT == I0 + I2, 
   I1 == IT + I3, \[Beta]1 == I2/I0, \[Beta]2 == I3/IT, 
   VBE1 == V1 - V2, VBE2 == V2 - Vi, Ib == I2 + I3, I1 == Vi/R1, 
   I2 == (Vb - V3)/R2, I3 == (Vb - V4)/R3}, {Ib, IT, I0, I1, I2, I3, 
   V1, V2, V3, V4}]]

Out[1]={{Ib -> (Vi (\[Beta]1 + \[Beta]2 + \[Beta]1 \[Beta]2))/(
   R1 (1 + \[Beta]1) (1 + \[Beta]2)), IT -> Vi/(R1 + R1 \[Beta]2), 
  I0 -> Vi/(R1 + R1 \[Beta]1 + R1 \[Beta]2 + R1 \[Beta]1 \[Beta]2), 
  I1 -> Vi/R1, 
  I2 -> (Vi \[Beta]1)/(
   R1 + R1 \[Beta]1 + R1 \[Beta]2 + R1 \[Beta]1 \[Beta]2), 
  I3 -> (Vi \[Beta]2)/(R1 + R1 \[Beta]2), V1 -> VBE1 + VBE2 + Vi, 
  V2 -> VBE2 + Vi, 
  V3 -> Vb - (R2 Vi \[Beta]1)/(
    R1 + R1 \[Beta]1 + R1 \[Beta]2 + R1 \[Beta]1 \[Beta]2), 
  V4 -> Vb - (R3 Vi \[Beta]2)/(R1 + R1 \[Beta]2)}}
```

---

Now, when \$\beta_2\to\infty\$, we get:

$$\lim_{\beta_2\to\infty}\text{I}_3=\lim_{\beta_2\to\infty}\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\beta_2}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\beta_2\right)}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\lim_{\beta_2\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\beta_2}}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+0}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\tag{10}$$

Comment: The point of an academic assignment is to work things out for onself with paper and pencil and an understanding of the concepts. Not to use software for what the student is supposed to be learning to do manually, and *certainly* not to have someone on an internet site simply hand you the answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is not true! I am allowed to use Matlab for example and Mathematica is kind of the same, so you're comment is not usefull.

Comment: @Derik what did you actually *learn* from this posting which simply handed you the answer?  Was it what your professor hoped you would, when they assigned the problem?

Comment: @Derik When I was studying for my degree in electrical engineering I was also allowed to use software in practical problems. For test problems of course not, but if you understand the concepts it is good to learn how to program.

Comment: @Derik How are you parsing this sentence that I write. Letter by letter, or word by word? Compare the answer with high upvotes to the one you've accepted. The former deals with electronic design 'words', Jan's deals with letters, the hard way. Think h o w y o u w a n t t o l e a r n i n t h e f u t u r e, and whether words are worth t h e e f f o r t t o m a s t e r,

Comment: @Derik I am admin here. My task is to TRY to ensure that comments and answer and questions all conform to site guidelines and keep people happy(ish) and that 'all goes swimmingly'. What Chris is saying has merit, even if it doesn't come across in as useful a way as you may wish. You also have valid points. Using advanced tools can in some cases be useful and in others actually reduce your learning. Reading  other people's explanations using an advanced tool can be educational - but one too often sees people take the answers and miss out on the learning. Whether that applies here ...

Comment: ... we cannot tell as onlookers. || In this case if you understand what Andy says about op amp gain and also WHY Beta 2 needs to be high for the answer to be as shown and how the circuit causes the equation to apply then you are winning. If you cannot explain these concepts in relatively simple terms then you are missing out on a learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to prove it if you accept that an op-amp (even quite modestly priced op-amps) that use negative feedback, seek to ensure that the two input voltages (+Vin and -Vin) are identical.

In effect, what ever voltage you apply to +Vin (Vi in your example) results in the same Vi appearing on -Vin. This inevitably means that: -

$$I_{R_3} = \dfrac{V_i}{R_1}$$

Comment: This is the answer, at least the answer of an engineer, or carpenter. Jan's answer is the answer of the [King of Kings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0TalLrtZ24). Choose wisely!

Comment: Slurp slurp slurp.

Comment: @Neil_UK 's   marginally rude response notwithstanding, Andy's answer, while not actually wrong, fails to note the role of Beta2 in the problem. Andy correctly comments about the opamp's gain BUT they are asking about I_R3 and not about I_R1. I2 exceeds I3 by Ib_Q2. For infinite Beta2 these are the same. For some transistors beta can be low enough to matter in some cases.   | Andy knows this - he just didn't mention it.

Comment: @Andy - you may want to add some Beta_2 to the slurping.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon well, I stayed clear of it because although the OP mentioned a "darlington" (and that overcomes the beta thing by another factor of 100 or so), the OP's circuit isn't strictly speaking a darlington configuration.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes - not a Darlington - and they "clearly" want I1 and I3 to match for the purposes of the problem so have said  Beta2 is very high. But they could have said I1 and avoided the problem - so they are making some point where the high beta matters. So it seems worth noting why it matters. Maybe :-)

Comment: Well, the question (now closed) asks to prove stuff when when β2→∞ so I'm minded to think that the job is done.